# dbms_sql.native and bulk collect

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to select from table of objects while using dbms_sql.native?
I have defined an object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SI_O IS OBJECT(
    S_ID   NUMBER, 
    P_ID   NUMBER, 
    G_ID   NUMBER,   
    DLT    VARCHAR2(255), 
    ERROR_ID NUMBER,
    B_ID   NUMBER
);
```

I also defined a table of objects:

```
   create or replace type SI_T is table of si_o;
```

Now I'm trying to use it in a procedure like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NATIVE_TEST IS
sqlCommand VARCHAR2(320);
tRows SI_T;
num BINARY_INTEGER:= -1;
l_ntt_desc_tab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
cur INTEGER;
cnt   INTEGER;
nrowCnt   INTEGER;

BEGIN   
    
    sqlCommand := 
    '  SELECT SI_O(S_ID, P_ID, G_ID,   DLT, error_id,B_ID) FROM MYTABLE' ;      
    
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommand BULK COLLECT INTO tRows ;
     sqlCommand := 'select count(*) cou from table(tRows)';
     -- here is what I wish:         
     cur := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
     
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur,sqlCommand,dbms_sql.native);
    nrowCnt:=DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(cur);
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(cur);
END NATIVE_TEST;
```

However I'm getting runtime exception ora-00904 "TROWS" invalid identifier. Everything is here simplified but I really wish to use dbms_sql.native like that ( if it would be posiible).

Comment: [DBMS_SQL.BIND_VARIABLE_PKG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_SQL.html#GUID-EBEDD4D2-EC2C-4E96-AB57-40AC7E009BBF) looks promising.

Comment: It works fine. If you want, you can put your hint as an answer.

Comment: It was only a hint. I am curious how you did it? Can you post your solution as answer? Because I had problems and now I have not access to Oracle 21.

Answer (score 1):

So, the trows is a plsql table that is in the memory allocated for plsql, while a select can operate only on objects in the database.
You do not need to run a sql statement to get the count of a plsql table.
You simply have the trows.count attribute, which you may invoke in the pl/sql block where that trows is defined.

Comment: The code above is simplified. In reality I wanted to have  some tables  in a memory and count stuff there based on many different cronditions, union these tables etc..

Comment: Then, I'd rather avoid using plsqltable. Maybe global temporary tables, eventually with on commit preserve rows would do better. Because global temporary tables may be manipulated in SQL, while plsql tables residing in memory may not be manipulated using SQL.

Comment: Maybe for operating with pl/sql tables, the following will help: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/collections-8i#multiset-operators